# Задача на круги Эйлера(тип задачи на 3 круга)

Tags: информатика

[image: таблица задачи]

Я переломала себе все мозги, СОВСЕМ не могу найти ответ.Всё,что у меня получилось:
200-70=130 f+c

450-160=290 a+b

450-70= 380 a+d

490-160=430 f+g

Помогите,пооожалуйста :(

Comment: Лучше нарисовать три окружности С, К, Э, пересекаться будут только две пары, сумма всех составит Суфле + Эклеры - (общ.СЭ) + Корзина - (общ. СК)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что это школьная задачка на множества.

Answer (score 1):

Ну нарисовали бы эти круги, все же станет понятно.

В середине Суфле, от него откушены две части на 160 и 70, остаётся 220.

220+200+490=910